# Updating every cell of of a table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with *m* columns and *n* rows. The ETL tools I 
was using wrote an empty (`''`) to every cell without a value and I would like
them to be `NULL` instead.  This got me thinking if it would be
possible to `UPDATE` every cell with value `''` with a `NULL`, in a single statement?
In my table every column happens to be `VARCHAR` (or `CHARACTER VARYING`).

```
    Col1|Col2|...|Coln          Col1|Col2|...|Coln
Row1   a   ''  ''    1      Row1   a NULL NULL   1
Row2   c   ''   e   ''      Row2   c NULL   e NULL
...                     -->  ...
Rown  aa    f  ''  123      Rown  aa    f NULL 123
```

Is it possible with SQL?  How about PL/pgSQL?  I did some 
googling around but couldn't find anything really relevant.

Comment: Really? Did you try something like: `UPDATE table SET Col1 = NULL WHERE Col1='';`

Comment: Seems to me like you didn't do any "googling" at all, or we don't understand your question as it speaks of a simple `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I'm guessing the asker is wondering if there's an easy way to write the SQL for all columns.

Comment: "- - would [it] be possible to UPDATE every cell with value '' with a NULL". Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Would it be possible to update every column in a single query.

Comment: Do you mean iterating over table and column names as variables? so something like this? foreach table $t foreach column $c update $t set $c='' where $c is null you will need to use a procedure for this. (mine is only pseudo code how I interpret your question)

Answer (score 6):

You can use either n `UPDATE` statements, one for each column:

```
UPDATE table SET Col1 = NULL WHERE Col1 = '';
UPDATE table SET Col2 = NULL WHERE Col2 = '';
---
UPDATE table SET ColN = NULL WHERE ColN = '';
```

or one with [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
UPDATE table 
SET Col1 = CASE WHEN Col1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE Col1 END,
    Col2 = CASE WHEN Col2 = '' THEN NULL ELSE Col2 END,
    ---
    ColN = CASE WHEN ColN = '' THEN NULL ELSE ColN END 
WHERE                                           
    Col1 = '' OR Col2 = '' OR ... OR ColN = '' ;      --- optional WHERE clause
```

The `WHERE` clause is not needed. But in case you run this again later, when there are very few rows with nulls, it will help to keep the transaction "smaller", updating only those rows and not the whole table.

Another equivalent, just shorter syntax, using the [`NULLIF()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) function:

```
UPDATE table 
SET Col1 = NULLIF(Col1, ''),
    Col2 = NULLIF(Col2, ''),
    ---
    ColN = NULLIF(ColN, '')
WHERE                                           
    Col1 = '' OR Col2 = '' OR ... OR ColN = '' ;      --- optional WHERE clause
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea based on the interpretation from this question.

This sentence is quite hard to understand:

`UPDATE every cell with value '' with a NULL`

Does it mean that you want to put `''` in every column with `null`?

If so, You can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE COLUMN `col` `col` VARCHAR(xxx) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE COLUMN `coln` `coln` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

This will set all `null` values to `''`. On numeric columns, it will set to `0`.

**Warning**: According to a comment, this is INVALID syntax for Postgres.

If you means the oposite, @ypercube's answer is the correct one.

Comment: The syntax is not valid for Postgres.

Comment: And what is confusing?: *"The ETL tools I was using wrote an empty ('') to every cell without a value and I would like them to be NULL instead."*

Comment: Yeah, I got stuck on `UPDATE every cell with value '' with a NULL` and couldn't understand it fully. I will keep the answer here anyway but marked as community wiki, just in case someone is looking for it.

Comment: Then update your answer with valid Postgres syntax.

Comment: I can't, I have no way to test it. But I will check the syntax.

Comment: You can test at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15

Comment: I know that website. It takes 50 millenniums to run a simple `select 1`.

Comment: It's sometimes not responding, yes. But it's quite good - when it does ;)

Comment: "sometimes"... I'm waiting for half an hour for it. Lets see how much longer I have to wait...

Comment: I guess I won't be able to test it. I waited 50m and it didn't went any further than the "Building schema" part...

Comment: Also, you'd still have to do it for each column separately. The point was to do it in one go for the whole table.

Comment: @JamesBrown You can do it in a prepared statement, where you read the definition of the table, the data types for each field, you build a query in a string and then you run it. I used this trick in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474662/mysql-optimize-all-tables/22091156#22091156